# install scan_tools packages

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I tried to install scan_tools packages. By the package csm everuthing was fine and compiled it perfectly. But by the second package laser_scan_matcher I got error. I update the workspace and add the package path.Also run the command
sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev
before istalling the packages . I got this error

```
 CMake Error: The source directory "/home/freek/svn/POW/ROS/Fuerte/external_packages/scan_tools/laser_scan_matcher" does not exist.
  Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

Any help¿

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37718/install-scan_tools-packages/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-07-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-02**:
Does that file exist?

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-07-03**:
Why are you using CMake? Does rosmake not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how to find out where cmake is called? I update the package path, so have to correct the source path also?

---

Originally posted by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) with karma: 330 on 2012-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-07-03**:
ok. Solved

**Comment by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on 2015-09-27**:
Could you let me know how you solved the problem? Thanks!